# Generate values with np.random

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I try to add new column to df, where all values there 0 or 1. 
I use

```
df['name'] = np.random.randint(0, 1)
```

But it returns column with all `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the shape specifier to let it create an array of random integers in the interval `[0,2)` that is `0` or `1` and of length same as the number of rows in the `dataframe` with `np.random.randint(0, 2,(df.shape[0]))` and then assign as the new column. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
df['name'] = np.random.randint(0, 2,(df.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** The upper bound is exclusive with this [function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

---

You should consider using :

```
np.random.randint(0, 2, nb_col)
```

Where `nb_col` is the width of your array.

Comment: This will generate a single number and all rows will be the same.